# How to check if a multivariable function intersects with a 4D cuboid

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given the case we have a multivariable function $f(x,y,z)$ and a hypercuboid defined by its intervals $[x_l,x_u], [y_l, y_u], [z_l, z_u], [w_l, w_u]$ where $f(x,y,z) = w$.

How can we check if $f$ intersects with a hypercuboid? I'm not looking here for an explicit example for the beginning, but more on the general idea how to approach such a problem :)

Edit/Update:
Assume that our function would be e.g. the following:
$f(x,y,z) = x*sin(c*y+z)$.

This function is periodic and continuous. Computing the extreme points would be achieved by computing the Hessian. But how can we compute the min and max within given intervals like in our example?

Thank you in advance for any hints,
Dan

Comment: A naive way to check this would be to check whether $f(x,y,z) \in [w_l,w_u]$ over all the points. A less naive way, assuming $f$ is continuous, would be to check the maxima/minima of $f$ over the cuboid determined by $x,y,z$ - if max & min are both greater than $w_u$ or both less than $w_l$, then there is no intersection, otherwise there is some intersection. If you give more info about your specific problem, people may be able to help further.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have added a function as an example. What would be a good way to compute the min/max over the cuboid intervals? I had the hessian matrix in mind.